# How to get the latest ChangeLog token from a CMIS server, via command line?

Tags: command-line, cmis

I have a [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) server, and would like to quickly know its latest ChangeLog token.

How to get the latest ChangeLog token from a CMIS server, via command line?

Solutions compatible with all versions of the CMIS protocol are preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command line outputs the latest ChangeLog token:

```
wget -q -O - --user=admin --password=admin \
"http://server/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom/changes" \
| sed -e "s/.*<cmis:latestChangeLogToken>//g" | sed -e "s/<.*//g"
```

- First line: Replace with your username/password
- Second line: Replace with your CMIS server URL and URL pattern before the `?`.
- Third line: Result filtering, leave as is.